# Xpath to find an(y) Character Entity?

Tags: xpath

I am hoping for an xpath to find any entity. End goal would be schematron or XSLT to do a report. Stuff like & − ← ε

Best I've managed so far is a regex search using oXygen: `&#x\w*?;` -- but that's not giving me the level of detail that I could obtain with schematron and it won't work with xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the tree is built, the entities are resolved.

If you're just looking for something like non-ascii characters, you could use the category escape `\p{IsBasicLatin}`.

For example, with this XPath (version 2.0 or higher):

```xml
//text()[normalize-space()][replace(.,'\p{IsBasicLatin}','')]
```

and this XML:

```xml
<doc>
    <para>Test</para>
    <para>Here is a non-ascii character: ε</para>
    <para><![CDATA[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`1234567890-=\][';/.,~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><]]></para>
</doc>
```

only the following text node is returned:

```
Here is a non-ascii character: ε
```

I'm not 100% sure how that would work with some of the spacing characters, but it might get you pointed in the right direction.

It also won't find something that's a basic latin character since there's no way to know if it was a literal character or an entity reference. (Your question mentions `&amp;`, but unless the `&` is in CDATA, it has to be escaped anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this related question about how to access XML declarations in XSLT. [How to access XML declaration part using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73117770/how-to-access-xml-declaration-part-using-xslt/73118727#73118727)

The problem you have is that (like XML declarations), entity references are not part of the XML Data Model, and are therefore unavailable to XPath expressions in a Schematron or XSLT stylesheet. [As Daniel Haley says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73380755/7372462), they have already been resolved as part of the process of parsing the XML document and constructing an XDM tree.

If you have an environment supporting it, the XPath 3 function `unparsed-text()` will allow you to read the XML file without parsing it as XML. You would then be able to use XPath string functions such as [`analyze-string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-analyze-string) to find entity references in the text.

e.g. an XPath 3 expression like this might do the trick:

```
analyze-string(
   unparsed-text(''), 
   '&amp;[^;]+;'
)//*[local-name()='match']/text()
```

(Note that I escaped the ampersand as `&amp;` in that expression so that the expression is ready to be pasted into an XML document such as an XSLT stylesheet or Schematron schema)